# Getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object when we invoke http request from BluePrism tool

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I have done configuration in Blueprism RPA tool to invoke REST POST Call.

I am getting following error when I ran it .

"Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Please let me know why we get this error and let me know if you need more information about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely means there is no response and exception handler tries to reference it.
Remove try-catch to see a real error. Blueprism VBOs are shit.